# Error occurs when install on AndroidO device (with signalR for java)

Tags: java, android, signalr

I have an old project that work fine on previous Version(previous form android O).
But it just cannot install on android 8.0

I tried to build a new project file to find problems.
I found....
[The signalr-client-sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px5eF.png)

after I add signalr-client-sdk to a whole new clean project then the next problem will happen :

[failed to extract native libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPcmN.png)

Please, what's the problem?

Edit : This is my test sample, this project is empty ,except adding a jar file in libs.
https://github.com/Yong-You-Ming/AndroidSignalR

Comment: Remove your old application and then install new one...

Comment: I tried, but not working. more to refer . The signalr-client-sdk is the only problem. the other jar file won't  cause this problem like gson .

Comment: Go to application where all the applications are installed..check from there does application exist or not?

Comment: I doesn't install on devices

Comment: It will not install after this error happen

Comment: @ShivamOberoi it does not exist